# Returning distance from query point with nearSphere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to query my collection using geoSpatial query to return results near to a point, along with the distance from that point.

I'm using `Queryable#near_sphere` with Mongoid http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html
This executes the $nearSphere command on the query.

I've seen the `geoNear` command:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-geoNearCommand

This seems to return the results, with the calculated distance

Is there a way to either:

a) return the distance using nearSphere
  b) use geoNear with Mongoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this command is available on Origin, you might open a feature request if you wish https://github.com/mongoid/origin/issues.

As a work around you can issue the command straight from moped, something like this:

```
Person.mongo_session.command({ :geoNear => 'places' })...
```

than you can put together your command, following the docs from mongodb.